# How to save Map objects in Java to MySQL database

Tags: java, sql, mysql, jdbc, dictionary

I have Java Map (out of Strings and Ints) objects that I want to save to a database. 
Is there a standard way to go about this task?
Is there a way to compress the Map to take less space on the harddrive?

Comment: Have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369916/serializing-a-java-map-to-a-db

Comment: As a java object or the data it contains?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually ask two different questions:

- How to save a Map object to a database

You need to create a database and an appropriate table. You can of source serialize the Map into a binary object and store that in the database as a BLOB. It will be better however to have a table entry for every object in the map. You need to use the [JDBC API](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/database/) to communicate with the database.

- How to compress the Mao to take less space in the hard drive?

You need to [serialize](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) the Map to a file. The map will be saved in a binary file, which you can try to [compress](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/).